# What does "buy in" mean in the context shown in this Dilbert comic?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this Dilbert comic strip from 09/27/2015...

[image: Dilbert comic]

(Strip source: http://dilbert.com/strip/2015-09-27)

...the C.E.O. says in the last square:

> I just need buy-in for the strategy

What does "buy-in" mean in this context and why is it used here (i.e. is it a case of using a term that is normally used in some similar but different context)?

Comment: I think it comes from card games when the right to play a hand is "bought" by each player before the cards are dealt.  The agreement to pay a fee (in the business world expressed by effort or time) is the "buy-in" - as in "I am paying to be counted **in**".

Comment: This appears to be a colloquialism used mostly in the US: [Oxford](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25484?rskey=S1zlbt&result=3#eid67948408)

Comment: @JohnB it is even a common loanword (or should I say loanwords?) in Dutch.

Comment: @Glorfindel Interesting. I wonder where else it might be commonly used.

Comment: [***buy in***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+in) #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy-in would refer to the business being on board with the proposal.

> I just need buy-in for the strategy

In this instance, the co-worker has an idea that will fix the declining revenue, if he can only convince the decision makers to support him, he can then implement his strategy with company backing. (Not necessarily financial backing)

Comment: Actually, the bald-headed guy is the CEO of the company, and he _is_ the decision maker. In this case he's asking for cooperation from the lower-ranking employees.

Comment: The egg-headed guy is the CEO, and he is trying to con his employees to trust his new strategy (which Dilbert correctly dismisses together with the con). Wally (being Wally) asks for a raise because he does not care about the company or doing his job right, just increasing his paycheck.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge Dictionary definition of buy-in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/buy-in) - the ​fact of ​agreeing with and ​accepting something that someone ​suggests:
*If you ​want to go ​ahead with these ​plans, you'll need buy-in from the ​employees.*